# get field names using JQ from XML

Tags: jquery, xml

I have this code to find two values from my XML file

```
    $(data).find('NameSearch').each(function(){
        name =      $(this).find('sitelist').text();
        address1 =  $(this).find('address1').text();
    }); // find loop
```

My XML file looks like this

```
        <sites>
            <NameSearch>
                <sitelist>EvertonFC</sitelist>
                <address1>Goodison Park</address1>
                <event>Everton Removal of old kit</event>
                <jobnumber>1081</jobnumber>
            </NameSearch>
        </sites>
```

Can anyone tell me how I can find the values of all the fields returned inside 'NamesSearch'

Hope this makes sense ? any help would be much appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

first thing never parse the xml using the jQuery DOM traversal methods it's very browser dependent, use [`$.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

```
var xml = "<sites>\
        <NameSearch>\
        <sitelist>EvertonFC</sitelist>\
        <address1>Goodison Park</address1>\
        <event>Everton Removal of old kit</event>\
        <jobnumber>1081</jobnumber>\
        </NameSearch>\
        </sites>";
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
    $xml = $( xmlDoc );

$.each($xml.find("NameSearch"),function(i,v){
console.log($(v).text());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4hhGn/4/)